# Installing Cygwin x11 package

Tags: cygwin, x11

So iam trying to install this :

http://rcc.its.psu.edu/user_guides/remote_display/cygwin/

And after about 2 hours, when i got to :

C:\cygwin\usr\X11R6\bin"

I only see two files : cygXft-1.dll and X-start-menu-icons.sh

Please help me as Ive spent about 3 days trying to do this and it stil doesnt work. What could i possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Just to add, I have installed all the files now and the other files still dont show up. Is there anything that Iam missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those instructions are at least 4 years out of date (probably more) and no longer correct.

X11 doesn't install into /usr/X11R6/ anymore.

You might find the instructions at http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/cygwin-x-ug.html helpful.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the reply. I followed the above and have some how managed to install the server. Now I am following this tutorial : 

http://physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-windows-quick-start.shtml

When i got to step 5) and typed in : $ wave

I get the following error:

/usr/bin/wave.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygxview-3.2.4.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Is there something missing?

Thanks.

Comment: In step 3 on that page, you should have installed xview to get /usr/openwin/bin/cygxview-3.2.4.dll and added /usr/openwin/bin to your path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. I have installed xview as described here:
http://physionet.org/physiotools/xview/#windows
The only thing i couldnt do was :
    run XWin -multiwindow -clipboard -silent-dup-error

I still get the above problem.

Comment: Again, those instructions referring to startxwin.bat are out of date.  You probably want to start the server with `startxwin -- +bs` and see http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-command-line-args

Comment: To fix your error about loading the cygxview-3.2.4.dll shared library, I can only suggest (i) checking that you have /usr/openwin/bin/cygxview-3.2.4.dll, and (ii) checking that PATH contains /usr/openwin/bin/ with `echo path`